# Where do i find cwm recovery for samsung captivate?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, clockworkmod-recovery, samsung-captivate

I rooted my 2.3.5 and then returned my Samsung Captive i897 to stock 2.1 update 1 ROM. But now I want to put cyanogen 9 ICS -- but the CWM recovery does not work anymore.

Where do I find one for 2.1? Kies does not want to update my phone to gingerbread. Eclair has no good apps, NONE, I am bored.

Comment: CM's wiki recently moved. The old content is here (incl. a link to a cwm): http://oldwiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/Samsung_Captivate:_Full_Update_Guide

Comment: That link is for android 2.3 build UCKK4 i have 2.1. that is the link i followed the first time.

Comment: Seems like 2.5 here is the most recent version: http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager

Comment: And by the way, there's CM10.1 for it. http://get.cm/?device=captivatemtd